# GNU-Screen super-key as escape

Tags: gnu-screen, hotkeys, key-binding, escape-characters, windows-key

The super-key (windows key, et al) isn't representable using ascii or terminal escape sequences, so I doubt a tty-oriented utility like `screen` would support it, but does it? Can I use the super-key instead of control+a to address `screen`?